# How to ORDER BY this statement?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

here's the code and its working. but I dont know how to ORDER BY this by fullname.

Check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/269a2/2

```
 UPDATE myTable
JOIN (
  SELECT m1.id, COUNT(m2.id)+1 ord FROM myTable m1
  LEFT JOIN myTable m2 ON m1.id > m2.id AND m1.company = m2.company 
  GROUP BY m1.id
) z1 ON myTable.id = z1.id
JOIN (
  SELECT 1 ord, '0000-1112' assign_num UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 ord, '0000-1501' assign_num UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 ord, '0000-1120' assign_num
) z2
  ON z1.ord = z2.ord
SET myTable.assign_num = z2.assign_num
WHERE myTable.company = 'company1'
```

Comment: There is some issue in #sqlfiddle...there is no order by in your query....further why you need order by in update query....

Comment: This is an update statement, why do you need order anyway ?